# Support of different languages in vespa

Tags: vespa

Is there any feature to get same document in different languages?

Here is my use case : If I am in USA then I should get data in english language and if I am in China I should get data in chinese language.

I don't want to feed different documents for different languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you got N translations of the very same document and you want to index each translation the simplest approach is to index each translation in a separate vespa document. Each language requires different tokenization/language handling (see https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/linguistics.html). You could do this per field but becomes complex to manage.

Your question does not really tell if you just want to store the data or search it but if you don't really *index* the data but only want to display the summary you could store the different translations in the same document e.g map where key is language and value is the actual contents.

Comment: Second approach is much better as its matches my use case, I want same document for different languages.Please upvote this if it is useful.Thanks Jo.